# Create and transfert array php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm searching a way to create arrays from a form and transfer it to another page:
This is my actual code :

```
    <?php
$nba = $_GET["nbadultes"]; // recup number of passangers
$adu = array();

for ($i=1;$i<=$nba;$i++)
{
    echo '<h3>Passager '.$i.'</h3>
        <label>CIVILITÉ</label>
            <select class="full-width" name="Civilite">
                <option value="Mr" selected >Mr.</option>
                <option value="Mrs" >Mrs.</option>
            </select>
        <label>FIRSTNAME *</label>
        <input type="text" name="FIRSTNAME"/>
        <label>LASTNAME *</label>
        <input type="text" name="LASTNAME"/> ';

    $adu[$i][civilite] = $_POST['civilite'];
    $adu[$i][FIRSTNAME] = $_POST['FIRSTNAME'];
    $adu[$i][LASTNAME] = $_POST['LASTNAME'];
}

$_SESSION['liste_adultes'] =$adu; 
?>
```

And this code in the next page to read the array :

```
        <?php 
        if (isset($_SESSION['liste_adultes'])) 
        print_r ($liste_adultes);
        ?>
```

But I don't know why the array is empty :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [Civilite] => 
        [FIRSTNAME ] => 
        [LASTNAME] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Civilite] => 
        [FIRSTNAME ] => 
        [LASTNAME] => 
    )

)
```

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` please.

Comment: counter question: was the session started for all pages using sessions? if not, then there you go.

Comment: `print_r ($liste_adultes);` you mean `print_r ($_SESSION['liste_adultes']);`? what's that `$liste_adultes`?

Comment: and make sure your POST arrays aren't empty. check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: *ah hah!!* `name="Civilite"` - `$_POST['civilite']` case-sensitive. Again, error reporting would have told you about an undefined index notice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to take care of the form inputs you send
2. As I can see, right now the form is not submitted, so you don't need a session but a form which have set the action to a page that handles the sent data. Something like:

   ```
   <form method="post" action="my-action-file.php">
   <?php
   $nba = $_GET["nbadultes"];
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $nba; $i++) {
       echo '<h3>Passager '.$i.'</h3>
           <label>CIVILITÉ</label>
               <select class="full-width" name="Civilite[]">
                   <option value="Mr" selected >Mr.</option>
                   <option value="Mrs" >Mrs.</option>
               </select>
           <label>FIRSTNAME *</label>
           <input type="text" name="FIRSTNAME[]"/>
           <label>LASTNAME *</label>
           <input type="text" name="LASTNAME[]"/> ';
   }
   ?>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   ```

In the `my-action-file.php` file you can get the `$_POST` variables as:

```
<?php
   foreach ($_POST['Civilite'] as $key => $civilite) {
       $firstName = $_POST['FIRSTNAME'][$key];
       $lastName = $_POST['LASTNAME'][$key];

       // now you have the sent data.. just use it like you need..
   }

   // of course you can add these data to an array if you like so
```

Comment: This looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

In the second page you need to read the session data, then read the specific value you saved in the session into the variable you used:

```
<?php 
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start();}
    if(isset($_SESSION['liste_adultes'])){
       $liste_adultes = $_SESSION['liste_adultes'];
       print_r($liste_adultes);
    }
?>
```

Also, in the first page, make sure you post data and read it with $_POST; or via query string with $_GET

Comment: you missed something also.

Comment: I had to sit that one out and merely pointed to her, the errors in the code.